# Wix react-native-navigation v2 dynamic tab

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have used `react-navigation` for my app. But, i want to convert to `wix [react-native-navigation] v2` to improve performance of my app.
However i have problem with dynamic tabs in `topTabs` or `bottomTabs`.

I have List Item Screen, Detail Item Screen.

In the `Detail Item Screen`, the first tab is detail of item that user have clicked from `List Item Screen`. After that, i have requested api to get related detail item to add in the last of first tab.

I have tried to user `setRootStack` but it didn't work.

Have any suggest to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs can't be added dynamically as they are part of the layout declaration and layouts can't be changed dynamically.

Comment: `ViewPager` in android or same in ios. Could you try it?